# proper way to load images from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Is it acceptable to store the img src="".... for an image in a database table column, or should only the location be stored and then somehow manipulated through javascript to load the image on the webpage?

Comment: MarcB described like that -  images in the database are almost always a bad idea, and sending everything out as base64 will boost your bandwidth bill by ~33%. Store the images in the file system and just store the image's PATH in the database, then you can load them trivially with a standard <img> tag.

Answer (score 1):

you would only store the image path (and possibly also the alt text and title) in the db and then add it into the webpage using php when the page loads. Note that in the following I am echoing each attribute independently. You can also put the entire image line inside an echo statement and cut out a couple of echoes with just the php db values listed as the attribute values.

```
//your mechanism of getting the data from the db

$imagePath=$Row["imagePath"]; //for example "images/common/logo.jpg";
$imageAlt=$Row["imageAlt"]; //for example "Our Company logo image";
$imageTitle=$Row["imageTitle"]; //for example "Our Company logo for 2016";

//image section of your HTML
<img src='<?php echo "$imagePath";?>' alt='<?php echo "$imageAlt";?>' title='<?php echo "$imageTitle";?>' height='50' width='50'/>
```

this will render as

```
 <img src='images/common/logo.jpg' alt='Our Company logo image' title='Our Company logo for 2016' height='50' width='50'/>
```

Comment: What I did was stored the path to the file in the database, let ajax build the html code for the image and send that to the javascript that called ajax which then assigns that to a div id.  Is this ok (it works) but I am not sure why or why not to store html code in a database?

Comment: You don't want to store the HTML in the database. You want to store that in the view concern, where if you want to change the presentation you can alter a file, not have to update your entire database row by row.

Comment: gotcha, I wasnt sure if it was a security concern or something else.  I have a significant amount of HTML code stored in the info (mostly just paragraph headers and such).  I can see why if I wanted to change it all how things would be easier to modify the ajax file and not each row of the database...thank you for clarifying that for me.